# qt-sdk - 'configure' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows-xp, qt-mobility

I'm trying to install the qt-sdk so I could use the qt-mobility headers.(on Win xp platform)
I downloaded the exe file and installed it, and now I'm trying to follow [these](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility/installation.html) instructions:

qt-sdk in installed 
I'm stuck in "Building On Windows" - it says to :

```
 cd c:\QtMobility\%DISTNAME%

 configure -prefix %TARGET_DIR%
```

do I created a nwe dir named 'QtMobility' and inside I created a new dir named Dist.
I get this error msg:

C:\QtMobility\Dist>configure  C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2008
'configure' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Am I doing it all wrong?
thanks a lot!